# i want to use async await without then or any callback funcion, but if check is not working

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Hi i want to use `async await` without any **callback** wrapper like

```
.then(function(){});
```

or

```
something(anyparams,function(){});
```

in other words i want to use my code line by line by converting promise into `async await`

**Problem:** i'm successfully converted `promise` into `async await`  if block is going wrong, how to fix that. expected output is **"result: FFF"**

**Here is my code:**

```js
function getName () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, rejected) {
        var name = "FFF";
        // wait 3000 milliseconds before calling resolve
        setTimeout ( 
            function() {
                resolve( name )
            }, 3000)
    })
}


async function foo () {
   console.log('Before Name');
   var name = await getName();
   console.log('After Name');
  return name;
}

var str = foo();

if(str == 'FFF'){
    alert('result: '+str);
}else{
   alert('entered wrong block');
}
```

Comment: `try catch` should do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `await` your async function call as well like so:

`var str = await foo();`

Comment: This is true, but you can only `await` inside an `async` function.

Comment: actually it worked for me,is the only solution, based on @Pointy comment i'm asking

Comment: @Pointy or with [top-level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await)

Comment: @EaB as long as your code is inside a module and the top-level await is working, you're good.

Comment: anyway @vzwick thanks for your solution

Comment: @vzwick oh cool they fixed the older crazy idea and now it seems sane and useful